# How can i change the values returned by parent class function in python

Tags: python, django

I have this code

```
class Mother:
        def getList()
            data['list'] = [2,3,4,5]
            data = json.dumps(data)
            return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json', status=200)



class Child(Mother)
      def getList()
          /////////
```

In the new function Here i want to get the list and do some modification like subtract some
              other list and resturn same  jsonresponse

How can i do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to abstract out the list generation part of your code from the response returning part.

This bit of code from Mother is, while not exactly invalid, not something that can work, either:

```
return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json', status=200)
return list
```

After the first return statement, Python isn't executing the method anymore, so the second return will never run.

Try splitting it up like this:

```
class Mother(object):
    def makeList(self)
        data['list'] = [2,3,4,5]
        data = json.dumps(data)
        return data

    def getList(self)
        data = self.makeList()
        return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json', status=200)

class Child(Mother)
  def makeList(self)
      my_list = super(Child, self).makeList()
      # do something to it
      return my_list
```

Now there is a `makeList` method on the Mother object, that constructs the actual list, and `getList` just formats it into an HttpResponse object.

In Child, `makeList` is overridden, but starts by calling the version from Mother. After that, you can do whatever modifications you need to, and return it. When you call `child.getList()`, it will use that new list, and then render it to an HttpResponse, since it inherits `getList` from Mother.

Comment: sorry that was typo , my second return statement is not there. its only httpresponse.  In your Child class , do i need to use the same return statement likr httpresponse

Comment: No, if Mother has a `getList` function like I've split it out, then Child will inherit that. `makeList` just needs to return the list itself.

Comment: thanks buddy i got it. it works but is there any way to make it work with one function only , without makeList function

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to do it, no. There are a couple of bad ways -- you could just write one big getList method in Mother, and another big getList method in Child, and repeat all of the common code, but that's not very maintainable. Otherwise, you could try to "reach into" the HttpReponse object, and extract its context before it gets rendered, but that means that your code is tightly coupled to the internals of HttpResponse.

Comment: i get this error `"must be type, not ChildResource",` on here `parent_list = super(self, ChildResource).make_list()`

Comment: Sorry, that should have read `super(Child, self)`. I'll update the answer. Also, make sure that Mother inherits from `object`, or `super` won't work.